# How to decorate spider leg drawing?

Tags: drawing

[image]

Problem here is that the flowers at the end of spider legs, appear to look more like knots tied to the end of his legs, than actual flowers.

I was considering putting tiny circles on those thin legs but then I realized they would look like it would give it a more "pimple"/bubble effect.

What are my options for decorating thin lines such as the legs. To make it look more realistic, but keep the whimsical look of the legs?

Comment: Real spiders have 2 joints in each leg. Yours has 1 joint in the front and hind legs, and none in the middle legs. Drawing these joints correctly would make the shape much more recognizable as a spider, even without the context of the web. Try googling "spider icon" for inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of tricky.
Adding an object to the front legs, the ones closer to its mouth. Such as an insect, or insect curled up in the web. A diamond or skull of some sort(whatever you would think would look cool to you).
Would direct the eyes to the front legs. Using current patterns you have on the page already, that could be collaborated in the other legs. Bringing the image as a whole  together.

Comment: That indeed makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Real spiders have 2 joints in each leg. Yours has 1 joint in the front and hind legs, and none in the middle legs. Drawing these joints correctly would make the shape much more recognizable as a spider, even without the context of the web.

A very simplistic shape with only one leg joint:

[image: Simple spider]

And here a more natural shape with 2 leg joints:

[image: Natural spider]

Although the shape of the body is almost the same, the first one resembles an ant or some other generic insect. The second one is unmistakeably a spider.

- the legs have 2 joints each
- the 2 front legs face towards the head, the 2 hind legs away from the head
- all legs join the body very close to the head

Try googling "spider icon" for inspiration.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you very much.